# Insert ViewController behind another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I currently have a main UIViewController that loads a webView. Based on a button clicked inside the webView, I have another UIViewController that loads another webView above the main UIViewController.

I do something along the lines of this in the main UIViewController:

```
self.newView = [[NewUIView alloc] initWithParam:param];
if (self.currentPlayer) {
  [self presentViewController:self.newView animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way that I can position the new UIViewController **behind** the main UIViewController.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your naming is very confusing.  NewUIView is a UIViewController right?  Did you mean insert a view from the new VC behind the main VC's webview?

Comment: I just named it NewUIView as an example. But yes, NewUIView is a UIViewController. I am trying to have the NewUIView get loaded BEHIND the main UIViewController.

Comment: You can only insert a view not a VC.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into UIViewController Containment...which allows you to have one view controller control more than one other view controller:

http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html